# Нормализация базы данных

Tags: sql

Имеется база данных с единственной таблицей условного приложения "Напоминания" со следующими полями:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Description
4. Category

Хотелось бы понять как удачнее реализовать функционал "корзины". Рассматривал вариант переноса выполненных напоминаний в отдельную таблицу аналогичную первой. Альтернативный вариант - создание нового поля "IsCompleted" и выводить относительно значения False.

Рассматриваю разницу с визуальной точки зрения и скорости обработки (выгрузки таблицы).
Элементы являются независимыми по отношению друг к другу.

Comment: Как вариант добавить поле "IsCompleted" в таблицу с типом tinyint (0/1). Далее view на эту таблицу с условием where IsCompleted=0

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения нормализации разницы нет. В одном случае у нас две сущности: "активные задания" и "выполненные задания", в другом одна сущность "задания" со свойством "признак исполнения"

С точки зрения производительности разница возникает при большом количестве записей.

Если это напоминалка для одного человека, то я бы выбирал между одной таблицей и отсутствием СУБД - хранением простым текстом (CSV, XML, JSON) в одном файле с обработкой на клиенте.

Если хочется сделать универсальную БД с возможностью расширения, то стоит озаботиться API: Процедур добавления, изменения, пометки исполненной; Процедуры/Преставления для выборки всех, исполненных, не исполненных.

При таком API легко менять способ хранения с одного на другой, то есть разделить таблицу на две, когда появятся тормоза при выборке.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!
В любом случае это будет база на "одного", ибо создаётся и хранится локально.
О чём изначально не написал - пишу приложение на C#, Xamarin.Forms и использую Entity Framework, а так же уже написаны методы для добавления, изменения, удаления, но вот не смог решить про пометку исполнения.
Значит пока останавливаюсь на одной таблице.